# RavenDb server security

Tags: ravendb

I'm hosting RavenDb on server. Database is available using url,for example aaaa.com:90 and everyone has access to it and can add,remove documents from server level. It is possibility to make access to ravendb server  depending on windows authentication?

Answer (score 2):

If ravendb on IIS7 then you need to :

create new user on server set permission on ravendb/web/data read write and
open iis manager select features/authentication and set windows authentication to enable,
and Anonymous authentication to disable,

do not forget use credential on your application,

[Go to RavenDB web site for more information](http://ravendb.net/docs/server/deployment/as-iis-application)